# difficulty giving alias to an import in python when using Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that is up and running, mostly in an easy-to-understand way.  But I have one quirky problem.

My code sits one level below where urls.py and views.py sit.  I have a number of Python files, some of which are used as imports across the actual code in the other impoPython files.

I have found that, as part of a Django app, I need to precede import filenames with a '.' for them to import.  So, if I have a file of code called foo.py, and an import file called vars.py, this won't import right:

```
# foo.py
 from vars import *
```

but this works:

```
 # foo.py
 from .vars import *
```

The problem comes if I try to be more Pythonic  (and safe) and name the import, so if I import everything it gets a prefix.  But neither of the following work at all:

```
# foo.py
import vars as v
import .vars as v
```

my presumption is Django (using virtualenv or through other means) defines certain paths to look up import files, and the '.' becomes necessary to point the Python interpreter to the same directory in which the importing file sits to locate the import files it needs to find.  But, somehow, this 'breaks' the ability to give the imported file contents its own prefix (or namespace, I guess).

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you try `from . import vars as v` ?

Comment: That was the answer.  Brilliant.  If you answer I can accept and upvote it.